# How to stream motion (jpeg) images/data from folder in C++ using Gstream lib?

Tags: c++, image-processing, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

i am trying to play sequence of image(.jpeg) from my local folder to play as h264 video in VLC player through local host connection.
I am using Gstreamer lib to stream support and i am using  from [test-launch.c](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c) from github  samples

OS : Linux 18.04
Gstremer ver: 1.14.2 Building from source using Cerbero

Following command is used to set the parser

> multifilesrc location=/home/user/Downloads/gen/img.%4d.jpeg loop=true caps=image/jpeg,framerate=10/1 ! jpegdec ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96

but no streaming happening insted i can see a error like below

> (Gstremer_img2vid2:21273): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 15:57:21.547: gst_bin_get_by_name: assertion 'GST_IS_BIN (bin)' failed

> 0:01:26.143446201 21273 0x55555592b850 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:3105:handle_setup_request: client 0x5555559d5260: no control in path '/test'

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have to provide size of the frames for jpeg decoding (here using 640x480):

```
test-launch "multifilesrc location=/home/user/Downloads/gen/img.%4d.jpeg loop=true ! image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=10/1 ! jpegdec ! x264enc insert-vui=1 ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay name=pay0"
```

Should be ok for receiving on localhost using vlc:

```
cvlc rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
```

Comment: @dinesh47, if this solved your case, you might check https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.